# Customizing JSQMessage bubble appearance

Tags: ios, user-interface, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

Is there an easy way to remove these chat bubble 'stalks' from certain messages? (I'd like to remove it from ones that are not next to an avatar image)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/1134) if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ya just create a variable for tailessBubble there is a tailess bubble image asset included in the library

```
let tailessIncomingBubble = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory(bubble: UIImage(named: "tailessMessageBubble"), capInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero).incomingMessagesBubbleImage(with: WeaveColor.Grey.incomingBubble)
```

Then just override the `messageBubbleImageDataForItemAt` method

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageBubbleImageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource! {
    let currentMessage = messages[safe: indexPath.item]
    return firstMessageInSet(indexOfMessage: indexPath) ? currentMessage?.senderId() == currentUser.senderID() ? tailessOutgoingBubble : tailessIncomingBubble : currentMessage?.senderId() == currentUser.senderID() ? outgoingBubble : incomingBubble
}
```

That should do it for you let me know if you need more help